# Unknown host exception thrown once in while

Tags: java, networking

```
String urlSD=" some url" ;
URL urlGetContents = new URL(urlSD);
DataInputStream rd = new DataInputStream(urlGetContents.openStream());
```

I am getting an `UnknownHostException` here. What made me confuse here is that it works well for a while (not throwing the exception for 50 times) and then the 51th time it will throw the exception. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

> How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Sounds like you've either got a malfunctioning DNS server or cache, or an intermittent network problem.  (Like my home broadband at the moment ...)

For a solution to the latter problem, try sacrificing a black rooster on your modem.

Comment: I do not think it is because of bad dns server or cache. Any way to resolve this issue problematically?

Comment: Are you always fetching the same URL?